# How do i get a list of records from two tables that have different values based on a matching PK?

Tags: mysql, join, primary-key, mysql-8.0

Lets say i have the following two tables:

Table1:

```
|IP    |Name  | Gateway | Version |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|1     |A     | 1.0.0   | v1      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|2     |B     | 2.0.0   | v2      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|3     |C     | 3.0.0   | v3      |   
+------+------+---------+---------+
|4     |D     | 4.0.0   | v4      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
```

Table2:

```
|IP    |Name  | Gateway | Version |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|1     |A     | 1.0.0   | v1      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|2     |F     | 2.0.0   | v2      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|3     |C     | 3.0.1   | v3      |   
+------+------+---------+---------+
|4     |D     | 4.0.0   | v10      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
```

How would i write a query to return a list of records from both tables that have **certain** different values based on the primary key (Lets use IP in this example)?

For example, if i chose to compare **only** Version and Name, the result would be:

```
|IP    |Name  | Gateway | Version |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|2     |B     | 2.0.0   | v2      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|2     |F     | 2.0.0   | v2      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|4     |D     | 4.0.0   | v4      |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|4     |D     | 4.0.0   | v10     |
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to join tables? How to compare two columns? Something else?

Comment: Either your sample output is flawed, or you description ("compare only ...") is flawed.

Comment: Could you please provide your table structures as DDL (`CREATE TABLE blah...`) and your data as DML (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...`)). Help us to help you!

Comment: *"Either your sample output is flawed, or you description ("compare only ...") is flawed"* @RickJames yes it is not complety clear atleast it as some  contradictions, i also had to read the question "300" times to understand how the expected result "worked"..

Comment: *"Could you please provide your table structures as DDL"* @Vérace see https://www.db-fiddle.com/ those kind off websites most of the time support importing from ascii based table output.. See blue button at the bottom "TEXT TO DDL" easy and fast..

Comment: Maybe it's a problem on my side, but all I'm getting is a blank db-fiddle site. What I was driving at was that you provide us with the table structures (DDL) and data (DML).

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE!  To help people better understand the question you're asking, this question would benefit from a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example).  Please provide some more context as the community definitely can help with these questions, but only when they have a sufficient level of information to work with.

Answer (score 2):

> Note MySQL 8 is has been released for more then a year now
>    which supports `COUNT(DISTINCT ...) OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` syntax..

There are multiple solutions possible,

Yes the solutions are hard, one of the problems is that MySQL does not (jet) support

`COUNT(DISTINCT ...) OVER(PARTITION BY ...)`

otherwise the solution would have been much more easy.

one of the solutions is.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

  SELECT 
   table1.*
  FROM 
   table1 

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT 
   table2.*
  FROM 
   table2 
) AS merged

INNER JOIN (

  SELECT 
     total_data.IP 
   , COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT total_data.Name) AS has_name_changes
   , COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT total_data.Gateway) AS has_gateway_changes
   , COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT total_data.Version) AS has_version_changes
  FROM (
    SELECT 
     table1.*
    FROM 
     table1 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
     table2.*
    FROM 
     table2 
  ) AS total_data
  GROUP BY 
     total_data.IP  
) AS search_filter
ON
   merged.IP = search_filter.IP
WHERE
   search_filter.has_name_changes = 1
 OR
   search_filter.has_version_changes = 1
```

**Result**

```
| IP  | Name | Gateway | Version | IP  | has_name_changes | has_gateway_changes | has_version_changes |
| --- | ---- | ------- | ------- | --- | ---------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 2   | B    | 2.0.0   | v2      | 2   | 1                | 0                   | 0                   |
| 2   | F    | 2.0.0   | v2      | 2   | 1                | 0                   | 0                   |
| 4   | D    | 4.0.0   | v4      | 4   | 0                | 0                   | 1                   |
| 4   | D    | 4.0.0   | v10     | 4   | 0                | 0                   | 1                   |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pAqbz4UWtCM3mqzw3rN87A/1)

The other solution which is even harder and only works when you have two records, one in each table.

**Query**

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;

SELECT 
   merged.IP 
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT_WS(
                ','
              , merged.Name
              , merged.Gateway
              , merged.Version
             )
             SEPARATOR ';'
           )
            , ';'
            , sql_number_generator.number
         )
         , ';'
         , -1
      )
      , ','
      , 1
    )
    , ','
    , -1
  ) AS Name
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT_WS(
                ','
              , merged.Name
              , merged.Gateway
              , merged.Version
             )
             SEPARATOR ';'
           )
            , ';'
            , sql_number_generator.number
         )
         , ';'
         , -1
      )
      , ','
      , 2
    )
    , ','
    , -1
  ) AS Gateway
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT_WS(
                ','
              , merged.Name
              , merged.Gateway
              , merged.Version
             )
             SEPARATOR ';'
           )
            , ';'
            , sql_number_generator.number
         )
         , ';'
         , -1
      )
      , ','
      , 3
    )
    , ','
    , -1
  ) AS Version


,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT_WS(
                ','
              , merged.Name
              , merged.Gateway
              , merged.Version
             )
             SEPARATOR ';'
           )
            , ';'
            , sql_number_generator.number
         )
         , ';'
         , -1
      ) AS merged_record
FROM (
  SELECT 
   *
  FROM 
   table1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
   *
  FROM 
    table2 
) AS merged
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 
   1 AS number 
  UNION
  SELECT
   2 AS number  
) AS sql_number_generator 
GROUP BY 
   merged.IP 
 , sql_number_generator.number
HAVING 
   MIN(merged.Name) <> MAX(merged.Name)
 OR
   MIN(merged.Version) <> MAX(merged.Version)
```

**Result**

```
| IP  | Name | Gateway | Version | merged_record |
| --- | ---- | ------- | ------- | ------------- |
| 2   | B    | 2.0.0   | v2      | B,2.0.0,v2    |
| 2   | F    | 2.0.0   | v2      | F,2.0.0,v2    |
| 4   | D    | 4.0.0   | v4      | D,4.0.0,v4    |
| 4   | D    | 4.0.0   | v10     | D,4.0.0,v10   |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pAqbz4UWtCM3mqzw3rN87A/3)